# Runtime polymorphism through virtual function in c++

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, runtime, virtual

This code gives me error which follows the base class pointer to store derived classs object. G++ compiler is giving error like this "error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘obj’, which is of non-class type ‘base*’"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Inside Base \n";
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Inside Derived \n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    base *obj;
    derived obj2;

    obj = &obj2;

    obj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `obj` is a *pointer* to a class, which means you can't use the non-pointer member select operator `.`. Your problem have nothing to do with inheritance or polymorhpism, you just have a very simple syntax error.

Comment: Note that you don't get polymorphism here, because print isn't declared virtual at base class (no virtual table is being created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Also take note that even if I change the code from obj.print() to obj->print(), it will be reference to the print() in the base class.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Inside Base \n";
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Inside Derived \n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    base *obj;
    derived obj2;

    obj = &obj2;

    obj->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not talk about how `print()` isn't virtual too?